# Android: how to convert byte array to Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays

I'm trying to convert one image from byte[] to Bitmap to show the image in the Android application.

byte[]'s value is got by database and I checked that it was not null. 
After that, I would like to convert the image but could not success. The program shows that Bitmap's value is null.

I think there are some problems in converting process.

If you know any tips, please show me.

```
byte[] image = null;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            if (rset4 != null) {
                while (rset4.next()) {
                    image = rset4.getBytes("img");
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length, options);
                }
            }
            if (bitmap != null) {
                ImageView researcher_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.researcher_img);
                researcher_img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                System.out.println("bitmap is not null");
            } else {
                System.out.println("bitmap is null");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your code, it seems that you take a portion of the byte array and use the `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` method in that portion. You need to supply the whole byte array in the `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` method.

**EDIT from comments**

You need to change your select query (or at least know the name (or the index) of the column that has the blob data of the image stored in your db). Also intead of `getByte` use the `getBlob` method of the [ResultSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/ResultSet.html) class. Let's say that column name is `image_data`. Having this info, change your code to something like this:

```
byte[] image = null;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        if (rset4 != null) {
                Blob blob = rset4.getBlob("image_data"); //This line gets the image's blob data
                image = blob.getBytes(0, blob.length); //Convert blob to bytearray
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length, options); //Convert bytearray to bitmap
        //for performance free the memmory allocated by the bytearray and the blob variable
        blob.free();
        image = null;
        }
        if (bitmap != null) {
            ImageView researcher_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.researcher_img);
            researcher_img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            System.out.println("bitmap is not null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("bitmap is null");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Please let me know how to supply whole byte array in that method.

Comment: Can you please specify what the `rset4` variable is? Seeing your posted code, that seems to have your image's byte array.

Comment: OK, rset4 is a value of ResultSet to store a result of executing SQL. 
`ResultSet rset4 = null; rset4 = stmt4.executeQuery("select * from images where id = "+ id);`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'd like to use `getBlob`, but unfortunately it occurs an error that notices `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Blob to 
 byte[]`. 
So do I need to convert from BLOB into byte array, and also from byte array into Bitmap?

Comment: @Benben I have updated my answer again. I apologise, i thought that the `getBlob` method of the `ResultSet` class returns `byte[]` and not `Blob`.

Comment: Guys if it is not working change `image = blob.getBytes(0, blob.length);` to `image = blob.getBytes(1, blob.length);`

Answer (score 22):

use below line to convert bytes into Bitmap, it is working for me.

```
  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
```

you need to put above line **outside of loop**, as it takes Bytes Array and convert into Bitmap.

P.S. :- here **imageData is bytes array** of Image

Comment: Thank you very much. But it does not work still now. I also use bytes array of image. 

Is there some problems in my bytes array...?