# Android Kotlin: Display image in bytecode

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview

I am building an app with Kotlin frontend/Python backend and I want to display an image that is in bytecode. My python script uses BytesIO() (https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) to return image's bytecode (ex. <_io.BytesIO object at 0x6f2496j0>) and I want to use kotlin to display its image.

Is this even possible?
If so, how can I assign image values to imageView id for example?
Sample code of it will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: how to convert byte array to Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613594/android-how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bitmap)

Comment: @LalitFauzdar I don't think I can solve it with the post alone. My guess is to use BitmapFactory.decodeStream to create a Bitmap and assign that value into a corresponding ImageView id. Is this correct?

Comment: @小尾穣 if you know how to convert a byte array into Bitmap then what challenge you are facing to set that bitmap into Imageview. Please describe your problem more specific

Comment: I'm still uncertain about converting byte into Bitmap since i never this tried before. Also i'm not familiar with assigning values to Imageview id dynamically so this is also new to me. Thats why I want to 1. know that my approach is appropriate and 2. have a sample kotlin syntax to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

//optional code

```
  val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.person)
val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
```

// assign bytes getting from seerver to byteArray

```
val byteArray: ByteArray = stream.toByteArray()
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```